# Can I put my views.py file in the project folder of django?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a project using django python server. I have created my project on django and put all my files including views.py in the project folder and I am using it without creating any app and its working fine.

Is this the right way of doing it (or) I need to create an app instead and put all my files in the project ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879036/django-projects-vs-apps?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work fine. Views can be wherever you want.

You can add the package that is your site (the one that has settings.py in it) to INSTALLED_APPS, and then a models.py in it, management commands, et cetera will also work fine.

Apps are handy when things become big and you want to split them into smaller parts.