# How to structure template libraries in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm in the early innings of the development process and am trying to figure out best practices for structuring the template libraries for a website.

I plan to have a "base" template to extend across the site.  I have seen some examples where a template directory is created at the project level to house this file, and others where a "base" file is created in one of the app folders and then extended to other apps as needed.  Is there a correct way this should be done?

Thank you in advance for humoring me on this extremely basic question.  Trying to get my feet under me for the first time.

Comment: You could use anyone of them. It really depends on your requirements. If you have multiple apps which follow the same html structure you can have the template at the project level. 

However, personally speaking, the reason we modularise anything is to get some amount of flexibility. I would suggest you to have base file for every application rather than project.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Would it be overkill to have base files at both the project level and the individual app levels?  (i.e., the app-level base files would extend from the project-level, then specific app html files would extend from that respective app's base file)

Comment: How is this an _opinion-based_ question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For site projects I tend to make the project module itself (as created by `startproject`) an app too.

That way base templates, base models (such as a custom user model!), helper utility functions, etc. live in there, and one doesn't have to futz around with the filesystem template loaders at all - the default app-based template loader works fine.

That is, if my project is, say, `grocerystore` and it has two apps, `drinks` and `foods` (silly example but bear with me), the structure would be approximately

```
manage.py
grocerystore/
    __init__.py
    settings/
        __init__.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        user.py
    views/
        __init__.py
    templates/
        base.html
foods/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        food.py
    views/
        __init__.py
        food/
            __init__.py
            food_list_view.py
        __init__.py
    templates/
        foods/
            food_list.html
drinks/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        drink.py
    # ... etc ...
```

and `INSTALLED_APPS` would contain (along Django defaults) `('grocerystore', 'foods', 'drinks')`.

You can then simply `{% extends "base.html" %}` in your apps.

(Note, btw, that to be able to split `models.py` into a package, you have to make sure `models/__init__.py` imports the modules holding each model, so they're registered by Django!)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for a year on Django. I think the best way to have templates in a separate folder. It means having a template in each app folder. It will be good to have a template folder and in this, we can have our app. You have to define template folder in the settings file.
[Plase check my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8RRQ.png)